# Reduction from Maximum independent set to Dominating set to prove the Dominating set is NP-complete

Tags: np-complete, proof

I know of the reduction from the Vertex cover to Dominating set.

However, I was seeing if I could get a reduction from the maximum independent set problem straight to the Dominating set problem in order to prove the latter NP-complete.

Does anyone know if this has been done? I can't find anything online.

I was hoping to find something along the lines of a proof like:

If there is a dominating set of size k -> there is a maximum independent set of size k.

AND

If there is a maximum independent set of size k -> then there is a dominating set of size k.

Comment: You can't show the first implication. V always is a dominating set, but in any graph with at least 1 edge, V is not an independent set.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get a reduction from the maximum independent set problem straight to the Dominating set problem -- but not that straight, you need to construct another graph in the following manner. We then can prove that if the original graph has an independent set of size `k` iff the new graph has a dominating set of some size related to k. The construction is polynomial.

Given a graph `G = (V, E)`  we can construct another graph `G' = (V', E')` where for each edge `e_k = (v_i, v_j)` in `E`, we add a vertex `v_{e_k}` and two edges `(v_i, v_{e_k})` and `(v_{e_k}, v_j)`.

We can prove `G` has an independent set of size `k` iff `G'` has a dominating set of size `|V|-k`.

(=>) Suppose I is a size-`k` independent set of `G`, then `V-I` must be a size-`(|V|-k)` dominating set of `G'`. Since there is no pair of connected vertex in `I`, then each vertex in `I` is connected to some vertex in `V-I`. Moreover, every new added vertex are also connected to some vertices in `V-I`.

(<=) Suppose `D` is a size-`(|V|-k)` independent set of `G'`, then we can safely assume that all vertices in `D` is in `V` (since if `D` contains an added vertex we can replace it by one of its adjacent vertex in `V` and still have a dominating set of the same size).

We claim `V-D` is a size-`k` independent set in `G` and prove it by contradiction: suppose `V-D` is not independent and contains a pair of vertices `v_i` and `v_j` and the edge `e_k = (v_i, v_j)` is in `E`. Then in `G'` the added vertex `v_{e_k}` need to be dominated by either `v_i` or `v_j`, that is at least one of `v_i` and `v_j` is in `D`. Contradiction. Therefore `V-D` is a size-`k` independent set in `G`.

Combining the two directions you get what you want.